# Unable to refer to a Textview in overlay class

Tags: android, textview, overlay

I have been trying to update a TextView field, when i Tap on the screen. I have implemented the Overlay class successfully, but I am unable to get a reference to the TextView field from the overlay class. I have passed 'context' from my activity class to overlay class.
What are the ways to get reference to the Textview in the overlay class ?

Comment: Some more detailed info and example code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options:

- You can pass the TextView itself to the overlay constructor.
- If the overlay is defined inside the activity, you can create a setTextViewText method in the activity that does it and call it from the Overlay.
- You can create a public setTextViewText method in the activity, not a general activity, and pass the activity to the overlay object.

Keep in mind that you can't modify an UI element from a non UI thread.

Regads.